# Choosing Gazebo , ROS , Linux version

Tags: ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm quite new to ROS.

**First Quest:**
I want to download ROS and gazebo in my VMware, but I am confused with the compatibility.
My Current Linux version is Xenial 16.04.1.

According to this [page](http://gazebosim.org/)
Gazebo 5.0 is compatible with ROS jade, so I plan to use them.
HOWEVER, my ubuntu version is Xenial, and according to that page they(the gazebo and the jade ROS) are not supported in Xenial(x) Ubuntu.

Moreover, There is no Gazebo version supported in Xenial version. AND the ROS version supported in Xenial version is only Kinetic, which is not compatible to any gazebo.

Do you have any suggestion and explanation on this?

**My last question is:**
For every gazebo and ROS version we can see that there is the EOL.
For example,
EOL for gazebo 5 is 2017-01-25
EOL for jade ROS according to this [ROS distribution page](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) is May 2017

Does it mean that after the EOL, we can no longer use it (gazebo and ros) ?
If so , then how? If no, what does it mean?
Please explain

Big Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241138/choosing-gazebo-,-ros-,-linux-version/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that Gazebo page is out of date. The [migration page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration#Gazebo_Simulator) for ROS Kinetic says:

> The Gazebo official versions supported in ROS Kinetic are the 7.x series.

Also Kinetic is currently the recommended ROS release, so right now the recommended setup is Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus + ROS Kinetic Kame + Gazebo 7.1.

End of Life (EOL) simply means that support ends for that version, in other words, the developers are no longer going to spend any time updating, patching, adding features, troubleshooting etc. that version. The reason they do this is so they can spend their time wisely on supporting more current versions and working on new features for future versions rather than fix things that most people aren't using anymore.

You are free to use something that is EOL, but if you find a bug the developers are probably not going to fix it for you. You could fix it yourself on your local copy, put up with the bug, or upgrade to the current version.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1